# Adding custom CSS to an HTML page rendered using webview

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I'm working on a Chrome extension where I'm loading an external HTML file using `<webview>`. I'm trying to include some custom CSS.

```
<webview src="https://example.net/" style="width:1280px; height:720px" autosize="on" minwidth="1280" minheight="720">
</webview>
```

I tried using `<webview>.insertCSS` – to no avail, unfortunately.

Can anyone help me? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it an id and then use that:

```
<webview src="https://example.net/" style="width:1280px; height:720px" autosize="on" minwidth="1280" minheight="720" id="MyWebView"></webview>
```

In JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById( "MyWebView" ).insertCSS( myDetails, myCallback );
```

**Warning: The javascript code must be called *after* the webview has been created, so in `window.onload` or in a script tag in the HTML code after the webview tag**

Edit: The `insertCSS` function allows adding a CSS file or CSS code: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#type-InjectDetails

Comment: Thanks a lot, but if I want to include some CSS code or a local file? .insertCSS('/path/style.css') ?

Comment: You can insert actuall CSS code or a file. See the definition for `InjectDetails`: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#type-InjectDetails This is the answer to your question.